# create regex to Extract the phone number from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in the following format that contains a index number, phone number, group Number and contact Name. Can you create some regex to extract all from follwing string ?

```
"AT+CPBR=1\r\r\n+CPBR: 1, "0342123456", 129, "simnumber"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"
```

Breakdown:

`"AT+CPBR=1\r\r\n+CPBR: 1` (Index Number)

`, "0342123456"` (PhoneNumber)

`, 129` (Group Number)

`, "simnumber"` (contact Name)

Comment: ya i tried to create its regex.. but i failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex escape characters are different depending on the language. Try this assuming that the middle 7 digits is the phone number.

```
\\"(\d+)\\"
```

this will return

```
0342123456
```

In the capture group.

**Update**

In re-reading your question I'm guessing that the escape sequences are escaped in your input string so that your *real* input is (\r & \n left in place for simplicity).

```
AT+CPBR=1\r\r\n+CPBR: 1, "0342123456", 129, "simnumber"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
```

With C# you can use the following

```
string s = "AT+CPBR=1\r\r\n+CPBR: 1, \"0342123456\", 129, \"simnumber\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
Regex rx = new Regex(@": (\d), ""(\d+)"", (\d+), ""(\w+)""");
Match m = rx.Match(s);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0]);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2]);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3]);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[4]);
```

This will result in

```
1
0342123456
129
simnumber
```

Remember that Groups[0] contains the entire match including the quotes.

Comment: @user665642 are the middle 7 digits the phone number - is that all you need?

Comment: no i want to break into groups like index Number, phone Number, groupNumber, contact Name
AT+CPBR=1\r\r\n+CPBR: 1(index Number), \"0342123456(phone Number)\", 129(groupNumber), "simnumber(contact Name)\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"

Comment: dear cordsen
i m only getting phone number by above regex.. i want to extract phone number, index number, contact person Name

Now consider the string

Comment: @user665642 - please update your original question with this information - this will help others in reading and responding to your question. Also please clarify on the quotes in the original string. I've updated my answer with a match to help.

Comment: @user665642 - I notice from your comments on the answer below that the contact name can contain spaces. In this case you should use something other than (\w+). Try either ([^""]) to match all non-quotes, (.*?) to  match all characters non-greedy, or ([a-zA-Z ]) to match all the characters included in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why do you want to use regex to extract phone # in above string. Why not use a variant of `split()` or `explode()` function on your text using space character and from the resulting string array take element # 2 (3rd element). In php you can do like this:

```
$arr = (explode(' ', '"AT+CPBR=1\r\r\n+CPBR: 1, \"0342123456\", 129, \"simnumber\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"'));
$phoneNo = trim($arr[2], '\",');
var_dump($phoneNo);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(10) "0342123456"
```

Comment: i want regex because this is one part of string .. i have many strings in the same format
e.g: 
AT+CPBR=1,200\r\r\n+CPBR: 1, \"9232123456\", 145, \"contactName1\"\r\n\r\n+CPBR: 2, \"0302125254\", 129, \"contactName2\"\r\n\r\n+CPBR: 3, \"030052145\", 129, \"contactName3\"\r\n\r\n+CPBR: 4, \"0331521456\", 129, \"contactName4\"\r\n\r\n

Comment: and kindly consider that i m using C#.net

Comment: You can use `str.Split(' ');` in C# to split it by space and you will get an array of `string` then it is a matter of removing enclosed  `\"`

Comment: if i splited the string with spaces.. the prob i will be facing is , my contact name also contains spaces.. e.g "contact Name 1" so this will break into 3 array indexes.... and secondly i want regex because .. i want to split above string in groups so that i can use it as e.g index Number, Contact Name, phone Number etc....